# Sum all values in row using Index/Match

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to build (what I thought to be a simple) Excel formula that matches a line item from one sheet with another line item from a second sheet and sums up all values in that matched row.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In *Sheet1*, cell **B3** enter:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(A3,Sheet2!A:A,0),2)&":" & ADDRESS(MATCH(A3,Sheet2!A:A,0),16384)))
```

[image]

There is probably a better formula than this using `INDEX()` rather than `INDIRECT()`